# What is this use of __init__ for?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I'm fairly new to python and I'm reading a book about creating games with pygame.  I came across this piece of code in the book.  I don't understand why `Sprite.__init__(self)` is necessary.  I have run the code with this commented out and it runs the same way.

```
class Creep(Sprite):

    def __init__(   
            self, screen, img_filename, init_position, 
            init_direction, speed)

        Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = speed
        self.base_image = pygame.image.load(img_filename).convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.base_image
```

Anybody have any idea why this is there and why people call **init**?

Comment: It's just a special method that acts as the constructor for instantiating a class object. (There's even a constructor for creating a class) You don't need it if you don't want to. ``self`` is just a convention name to say ``this``. Think of it this way, class methods like ``__init__`` needs a reference of itself and the first argument will always be ``self``. There is an exception though: staticmethod in a class. But let's not get there until you understand the init and self purpose.

Comment: `Sprite(self)` would achieve the same thing as `Sprite.__init__(self)` yet create an instance to do so. This usage is a little bit strange as it's calling the `__init__` method without taking the resulting instance.

Comment: Just noticed the `class Creep(Sprite):` - it looks as though this is equivalent to doing `super(Creep, self).__init__()` on the current class.

Comment: Not a duplicate, OP isn't asking what the `__init__` method is, he's asking why `Sprite.__init__` is called within it.

Answer (score 1):

This is calling the superclass initialization method. Presumably, `Sprite` does some initialization that you would also need in the subclass, and in Python you need to explicitly call that.

Normally, however, you would do it via a call to `super`:

```
super(Creep, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Ok. I think I have a vague idea of whats going on.  The class Creep also needs access to certain variables contained within the Sprite object's initialization call?  Forgive me if my lingo is a little off. Very new to programming.